# Python indexing from dataframe with iloc

Tags: python, indexing

I want to do something very easy, but I am new to Python and tried a lot of things, but it does not work. Say that I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([10, 20, 0, 30, 50], columns = [‘Values’]
```

The objective is to write a function that replaces 0 by the average of the pre and consecutive elemente, that is, `0 <- (20+30)/2 = 25`. Later on I want to use this function together with `apply` to apply it to every column of a much bigger dataFrame.

I did the following:

```
def avg_zeros(x):
    index = x[x == 0]
    x.loc[index+1, 0] = (0.5)*(x.loc[index, 0] + x.loc[index+2, 0]
    return(x)
```

However it keeps returning errors. I think the problem is with `index = x[x==0],`as it does not allow me to extract the index as an 'integer', but I tried different things and it does not seem to work.

Any tips? 
Thanks

Comment: What will you do if the first or last element has 0?

Comment: Thanks for the note. I will use an if-statement to check this and in case its the first element, then it should just take the second and in case of the last it should take the one before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([10, 20, 0, 30, 50], columns = ['Values'])

df.Values[df['Values'] == 0] = np.nan

df['Values'] = df['Values'].interpolate(how='linear')

print(df)

   Values
0    10.0
1    20.0
2    25.0
3    30.0
4    50.0
```

Comment: Very nice, this works fine! However, I would like to know if there is a possible way to modify the piece of code in my original post to make it work? I still don't know how to index properly.

Comment: You can practice indexing on your data frame without using .apply(). It might also be worth thinking about what will happen if 0 is in the start or end position of  the column. Will function compute valid indices? What about if you have several 0s in a row?